# Threading in Python with Timed While Loop

Tags: python, multithreading, time, ticker

A similar question was asked earlier but it didn't provide the correct answer.

I am trying to code to test threading in Python in which a ticker ticks every second. I am trying to keep the ticker function named 'clicking' running in a thread whose output is continously being incremented by one every second.

```
import time
import threading
import queue

q = queue.Queue()

apple = 0
orange = 0    
rate = 1
clix = 0


def clicking(clix, rate):
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        clix += rate
        q.put(clix)

threading.Thread(target=clicking, args=(clix, rate)).start()
curr = q.get()
print(curr)

print('\nClicker Starting...')
endgame = False
while not endgame:

    print(f'Clix: {curr}')
    print('1. Apple : 10 clix | 2. Orange : 8 clix  |  3. Exit')
    ch = int(input('\nPurchase ID: '))

    if ch == 1 and curr >= 10:
        print(f'You have {curr} clix.')
        print('Got an Apple!')
        apple += 1
        rate += 1.1
        curr -= 10

    elif ch == 2 and curr >= 8:
        print('Got an Orange!')
        orange += 1
        rate += 1.2
        curr -= 8

    elif ch == 3:
        endgame = True
        stopflag = True
    else:
        print('Need more Clix')
```

But my otuput is always 1 instead of incrementing every second by defined rate. What am I missing? I even tried `return clix` in place of `q.put(clix)` but didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you are not updating the curr variable inside the while loop. But do notice that when you write "curr = q.get()" inside the while loop it will get the next value in the queue and not the last value (as I suppose you intend). I guess a more straightforward approach is to keep track on the seconds increment inside your while loop using time.time()

```
import time

apple = 0
orange = 0
rate = 1
clix = 0
curr = 0

last_ts = time.time()

print('\nClicker Starting...')
endgame = False
while not endgame:
    ts = time.time()
    curr += (ts - last_ts) * rate
    last_ts = ts

    print(f'Clix: {curr:.0f}')
    print('1. Apple : 10 clix | 2. Orange : 8 clix  |  3. Exit')
    ch = int(input('\nPurchase ID: '))

    if ch == 1 and curr >= 10:
        print(f'You have {curr:.0f} clix.')
        print('Got an Apple!')
        apple += 1
        rate *= 1.1 # I guess you meant x1.1
        curr -= 10

    elif ch == 2 and curr >= 8:
        print('Got an Orange!')
        orange += 1
        rate *= 1.2 # I guess you meant x1.2
        curr -= 8

    elif ch == 3:
        endgame = True
        stopflag = True
    else:
        print('Need more Clix')
```

this way you can exit properly also, notice that on your example even when the loop breaks the thread continues.

but in case you want to maintain a background thread, I suggest creating a class and storing class variables for the current counter and run condition.

Comment: I specifically was looking at the usage of multithreading for this purpose wherein the clicker function runs on an alternate thread while the game is played on the primary code. This was as an experiment. Thank you.